# Si j'aurais avec et sans "même"

Tags: si

C'est une question bien plus compliquée que "les si n'aiment pas les rais".

Dans la phrase ci dessous:

> Même **si j'aurais** préféré que tu me la donnes, je te remercie de me l'avoir prêtée.

Antidote accepte le **si j'aurais**. J'avais entendu parler de l'exception lorsqu'on exprime une chose irréalisable, cas où ce  n'est pas une faute. À part la surprise que je sache cela, aucun prof ne m'a dit que c'était une faute. Même en l'absence de "même" car celui-ci est alors sous-entendu, le sens étant clair.

Je constate qu'Antidote accepte "Même", mais indique une faute en son absence. Probablement car il ne peut déduire le sens.

Il y a-t-il une référence solide quant à cette exception où est-ce un bug/erreur dans Antidote ?

Comment: a part la phrase de type "On m'a demandé si j'aurais préféré ne pas venir", le si + -rais ne passe pas. Est-ce qu'Antidote se trompe et croit être dans ce cas ?

Answer (score 3):

***Même si*** n'introduit pas ici une hypothèse ou une condition mais est équivalent à ***bien que***. Ces conjonctions introduisent une concession, on rapproche deux fait qui présentent une contradiction (cf. [coursdefrancais.net](http://xn--coursdefranais-qjb.net/exp_oppos.html)).

D'autre part, le verbe ***préférer*** exprime ici un souhait non satisfait qui impose le conditionnel passé (*même si **j'aurais préféré**...*) ou éventuellement un plus-que-parfait du subjonctif (*même si **j'eusse préféré**...*) Un souhait simple aurait lui imposé un conditionnel présent (*même si **je préférerais**...*) mais au moment où la phrase est prononcée, il est trop tard pour utiliser le présent.

Les autres temps du subjonctif, que ce soit le présent (*bien que **je préfère**...*), le passé (*bien que **j'aie préféré**...*) ou l'imparfait (*bien que **je préférasse**...*) sont exclus puisqu'ils changeraient le sens de la phrase. Seul le plus-que-parfait est compatible avec elle, mais improbable vu sa désuétude.

> ✅ Même si j'aurais préféré que tu me la donnes, je te remercie de me l'avoir prêtée.

> ✅ Bien que j'aurais préféré que tu me la donnes, je te remercie de me l'avoir prêtée.

> ✅ Même si j'eusse préféré que tu me la donnasses , je te remercie de me l'avoir prêtée.

> ✅  J'aurais préféré que tu me la donnes mais je te remercie de me l'avoir prêtée.

> ❌ <s>Si j'aurais</s> préféré que tu me la donnes, je te remercie de me l'avoir prêtée.

Dans cette dernière phrase, *Si* ne peut introduire qu'une condition, le conditionnel est donc exclu puisqu'il n'y a pas de condition dans la phrase.

Answer (score 1):

Cet usage de « si » ne relève pas  de la section  « **I** » de l'entrée de ce mot dans le TLFi ; c'est la section qui couvre les systèmes hypothétiques ; elle stipule ceci.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/si))  **I. − [*Si* introd. la protase d'un syst. hyp. (si p, q); il marque que la protase p est telle que, dans tous les cas où elle est vérifiée, l'apodose q l'est également]**

Cela revient à dire que l'usage du conditionnel, s'il figure dans cette subordonnée en  infraction d'une règle ou d'une autre, ce ne peut pas être la règle qui veut que dans les systèmes spécifiés par   « **I** » le conditionnel soit utilisé dans  la principale et qu'un temps de  l'indicatif le  soit dans la subordonnée introduite par «si».

C'est  la seconde section  qui est applicable à cet usage, et   plus précisément la  sous-sous-section « **B.1.** ».

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/si))
> **II. − [Empl. argumentatifs: dans tous les cas où p est vérifié, q l'est également]**
> **B. − [Si pose une rel. de type adversatif]**
> **1. [L'énonciateur, tout en admettant la vérité de p, allant dans le sens d'une conclusion déterminée, avance un argument q qui contredit cette conclusion]**
> • Dans l'ancienne société féodale, si le seigneur possédait de grands droits, il avait aussi de grandes charges (Tocqueville,Anc. Rég. et Révol., 1856, p. 107).B. − [Si pose une rel. de type adversatif]
> ., 1856, p. 107).

« Si j'aurais préféré que tu me la donnes » n'exprime donc pas une hypothèse mais une vérité. Les temps auxquels on s'attend sont  le présent de l'indicatif en particulier mais aussi d'autres temps (imparfait, passé composé,futur,etc.).

- Si je préférais que tu me la donnes, je te remercie (quand même) de me l'avoir prêtée.

Cependant, « préférer » n'est pas  n'importe quel verbe ; c'est un de ces verbes avec lesquels on utilise le conditionnel atténuatif, ou, pour  caractériser cet aspect moins généralement, le conditionnel de  politesse.

> ([réf.](https://www.google.com/search?q=conditionnel+politesse&client=firefox-b-d&ei=UPAQY52jIMeilwTziLLYDg&oq=conditionnel%2Cpolitesse&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQARgAMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBggAEB4QFjIGCAAQHhAWMgYIABAeEBYyBggAEB4QFjIGCAAQHhAWMgYIABAeEBYyBggAEB4QFjIGCAAQHhAWOgoIABBHENYEELADOgcIABCwAxBDOggIABCABBCxAzoICAAQHhAPEBZKBAhBGABKBAhGGABQmwdYgipgujpoAXABeACAAYQBiAHqCJIBBDAuMTCYAQCgAQHIAQrAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz-serp)) Le « conditionnel de politesse » s'emploie fréquemment avec les verbes : *avoir, désirer, être, pouvoir, préférer, souhaiter, vouloir*. Il permet d'atténuer la force d'une demande de service ou l'expression d'une volonté.

> - Je préfère qu'il ne vienne jamais au monde. (*fait dans le domaine du possible*)
> - Si je préfère qu'il  ne vienne jamais au monde, j'ai un petit espoir que mes sentiments changeront. (*relation de type adversatif*)
> - [Je préférerais/J'aurais préféré] qu'il  ne vienne jamais au monde. (*atténuation*)
> - Si je préférerais qu'il  ne vienne jamais au monde, j'ai un petit espoir que mes sentiments changeront. (*relation de type adversatif*)

La « proximité » des systèmes est trompeuse, mais après rationalisation, on se doit de conclure à une  grammaire correcte.
Il existe donc une possibilité logique d'utilisation du conditionnel (sans que « même »  précède « si »).

- Si [je préférais/je préférai/j'ai préféré] que tu me la donnes, je te remercie de me l'avoir prêtée.
- Si j'aurais préféré que tu me la donnes, je te remercie de me l'avoir prêtée.

Answer (score 0):

> J'aurais préféré que tu me la donnes, mais je te remercie de me l'avoir prêtée.

OK, langage de tous les jours.

> Bien que j'eusse préféré que tu me la donnes, je te remercie de me l'avoir prêtée.

OK, mais en langage écrit, pas parlé.

> Bien que j'aurais

Attention: selon de nombreux locuteurs, "bien que" est toujours suivi du subjonctif. Il y a désaccord selon les régions/pays.

> Même si j'aurais préféré que tu me la donnes, je te remercie de me l'avoir prêtée.

OK mais attention à la subtilité avec "Même si j'avais" qui renvoie à un évènement réel et pas hypothétique. Bref faire attention...

> Si j'aurais préféré que tu me la donnes, mais je te remercie de me l'avoir prêtée.

Horrible: "Si" seul est toujours suivi de l'indicatif.

Comment: Attention: *langage* en français. Ta quatrième phrase est curieuse (*mais* en trop?). D'autre part, [on recommande](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71/nutilisez-pas-les-blocs-de-code-pour-les-citations-do-not-use-code-blocks-for) d'éviter les tags de code pour autre chose que du code.

Comment: @jlliagre Corrigé. Pour la 4ème de ne devais pas être bien réveillé...